# The performance overhead of VMware Workstation for scientific computing

Tags: performance, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to understand the feasibility of running CPU-bound scientific programs in a VMware virtual machine, specifically a Linux guest in a Windows host. What sort of performance overhead should I expect? I.e. should CPU-intensive programs take 10% longer to run in the virtual machine? 20%?

Comment: This will depend on WAY too many factors for us to give you a straight answer.  "It depends" on what you're running, how many VMs, what hardware, what software stack, etc.  If you are talking about "rent-a-servers" then there's even more factors that make this pretty much unanswerable. IMO, if you need raw CPU for calculating then VMs are not for you, period.  You need to ensure you are using all of the system's CPU/cores to their fullest potential, as directly as possible.